# URL Forwarding when replying to mail with different DNS

Tags: email, dns, host, forwarding

I have a question that I don't know if it is feasible. Here are the specs :

I have one server with domain www.mywebsite.fr hosted on A. But I have also a domain www.mywebsite.com located on B.

What I want is to use mail addresses mail@mywebsite.com and never use mail@mywebsite.fr. I already made mail forwarding, so that when people send mail to mail@mywebsite.com I automatically receive it on mail@mywebsite.fr. However, is it possible to send a response (or a more general mail) so that when I send from mail@mywebsite.fr it goes trough mail@mywebsite.com so the person receive a mail (the response) from mail@mywebsite.com.

Sorry if I was not clear enough, but if you understood my problem and that it only requires DNS configuration I would really appreciate any help from your side.

Best regards.

Comment: So this is where you come to provide some sample of the code you have tried to make your application work. I do not see any of that above. Have you check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is nothing related to any coding aspect, more on configuration side.